# Allure report marking tests and test steps as passed but also indicating result is unknown?

Tags: node.js, allure, wdio

My allure report is marking my test and all steps as passed but the arrow to expand the test steps in the report is marked purple which I understand indicates an unknown result (css classes indicate this).

This only occurs for a few tests (most others have a green arrow for expand) but I can't really see a pattern as they use different types of assertions. Additionally I can't find good information when allure marks a test result as unknown.

Any ideas?

I am using WDIO and the latest allure (7.16.14)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by us having test steps which were not ended during our execution. Once we added an additional endStep call it is working correctly.

Comment: what do you mean endStep call? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Uniquename in the test script in the 'describe' block and add the 'done' method to execute all the bending test scripts execution.
Example:
describe('**login suite** ', async () => {
// Execute a block of code at the start of the test suite

```
before("init", async (done) => {
   await loginExecution() 
   done;
    
});
```